# Understanding If statement byte operators

Tags: c#, byte

I've downloaded some [source code](https://robot-electronics.co.uk/files/usb-rly02-cs.zip) for a USB controlled relay switch. I need to manipulate this code for an application but am having trouble understanding the byte operators.

I've had a look at bit-shifting operators and I understand they are shifting bits to the next power of 2. Below is the function I am struggling with:

```
byte[] SerBuf = new byte[64];
byte states = 0;
private void button_pressed(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           // Check type of sender to make sure it is a button
           if (sender is Button)
           {
               if (usb_found == 1)
               {
                   Button button = (Button)sender;
                   // Check the title of the button for which realy we wish to change
                   // And then check the state of that relay and send the appropriate command to turn it on or off
                   switch (button.Text.ToString())
                   {
                       case "Relay 1":
                           if ((states & 0x01) == 0) SerBuf[0] = 0x65; //<this is the bit I don't understand
                           else SerBuf[0] = 0x6F;
                           //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                           break;
                       case "Relay 2":
                           if ((states & (0x01 << 1)) == 0) SerBuf[0] = 0x66; //<this is the bit I don't understand
                           else SerBuf[0] = 0x70;
                           break;
                       case "Both":
                           SerBuf[0] = 0x64;
                           break;
                       case "None":
                           SerBuf[0] = 0x6E;
                           break;
                   }
                   transmit(1); // this sends the new buffer to the relay board

               }
           }
```

What I don't understand is what is being evaluated with `if ((states & 0x01) == 0)`

The `States` byte is between 0 and 3 depending on which of the two relay switches are active.

What is the `0x01` doing?

Comment: `&` is bitwise "and". 0x01 is binary 00000001. `((states & 0x01)` masks out all but the first bit of `states`; thus if states is `0x02` (binary `00000010`), `((states & 0x01) == 0`. If states is 0x03 (binary `00000011`), `((states & 0x01) == 1`. If states is 0x07 (`00000111`), `((states & 0x01) == 1` again .

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i understand `0x01` = 1. But if `states = 0` and `0x01 =1`, how does that evaluate to zero in the code?

Comment: states & 0x01 returns 1 if the lowest-order bit of states is 1, and zero if the lowest-order bit of states is 0. If states is 0, all the bits are zero, including that one. This is not a shifting operation; it is a logical operation. We call it "masking", for obvious reasons. `(states & 0x04)` would look at the third bit, because 0x04 == binary 00000100. 0x06 is 00000110, so that would look at the second and third bits. 0001100 & 0000110 == 0000100 -- only the bits that are 1 in both pass through the expression.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the explanation, got to it first.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - AHA! that makes perfect sense! thank you!

Comment: @EdPlunkett for my understanding `(states & 0x01 <<1)` is then masking all but the second bit, correct? so if `states = 1` (binary `00000001`) then it evaluates to zero, correct?

Comment: Yes, `(00000001 << 1) == 00000010`, and `00000010 & 00000001 == 0`. Sticky bit's answer nails it better than my babbling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator is the bit-and operator. It compares both operands bit for bit. Only if both bits at a position are set the corresponding bit in the result is set.

So lets say you have `a` and `b` where `a` presented as a bit string is `00001101` and `b` as `00001011`. Then `a & b` written as bit string is `00001001` because

```
           +----- no bit is set
           |+---- both bits are set
           ||+--- only one bit is set  
           |||+-- only one bit is set  
           ||||+- both bits are set
           vvvvv
a     = 00001101
b     = 00001011
----------------
a & b = 00001001
```

So in other words `(states & 0x01) == 0` is true if and only if `states` is even, i.e. written as a bit string it ends in `0`. Keep in mind that `0x01` is `00000001` written as a bit string.